# Certificate expiration and SHA-1

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, certificate

Background: I'm a complete newbie when it comes to certificates.

We have a site running at https://global.projacked.com

The certificate is issued by AWS.

All works well for most of our customers but...

One of them is experiencing the following:
[image]

[image]

[image]

And when I click on "view certificate" I see:
[image]

So the question is: can we do anything on our end to make this work?

If not: what can I tell my customer to do to make it work? Is it a question of them updating their certificate? Or might it be cause by them being in a secured network (e.g. VPN)?

Thank you immensely in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

Your site `global.projacked.com` is serving a [valid SHA-256 certificate](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=global.projacked.com&latest). The customer who has reported this issue appears to be having its HTTPS traffic intercepted and inspected by some sort of a MITM software or device (the Issuer -- `apotex-CA` -- on the certificate they're seeing gives it away). The MITMing entity is generating a certificate that is trusted by the customer's browser but it happens to be a SHA-1 certificate causing Chrome to complain.

You cannot do anything to fix their issue. A lot of MITM software vendors have released updates that create SHA-256 certificates to avoid situations such as this. They can probably check to see if there are updates they can install that generate SHA-256 certificates or read [this](https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/alerts/TA17-075A) or [this](https://insights.sei.cmu.edu/cert/2015/03/the-risks-of-ssl-inspection.html) to see if they really need to have TLS traffic intercepted and inspected. Sadly, I've seen organizations where the "solution" to this issue is to install an older version of Chrome that did not care about SHA-1 certificates and disable auto-update. After all, burying your head in the sand is very good at blocking all the noise about this little thing called security.

Answer (score 0):

The certificate issuer should be able to issue a certificate under SHA-256. You'll then need to replace the certificate on the server.

Some certificate authorities can give you new cert as a re-issue of the old one, some will require CSR (Certificate Signing Request) that can be constructed based on the existing private key, which likely resides on the server too.

Comment: The issuer is our customer's company. So shall I ask them to issue a new certificate? Our certificate is issued by AWS, I doubt I can ask AWS to issue the certificate in a different way :/

Comment: If you're using ACM, the certs are SHA-256. You can also issue your own. All in this guide (since your site runs on Elastic Beanstalk): http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html